# Анимация сглаживание появления

Tags: css, анимация, css-animation

как здесь сгладить эффект появления облаков , а то когда доходи [вот мой пример](http://price.extremje.bget.ru/optovyij-sklad/golandiya)

```
.moon {
    background: url("../img/oblako/cloud_one.png");
    position: absolute;
    background-size: 38%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-animation: moon 90s linear  infinite;
    -moz-animation: moon 90s linear  infinite;
    -o-animation: moon 90s linear  infinite;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    animation-fill-mode: backwards;
    animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards; 
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

}

@-webkit-keyframes moon {
    0%{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
    -o-transform: scale(1.4);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать `opacity`. Что-то вроде этого:

```css
body {
  background: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.moon {
  background: url("http://price.extremje.bget.ru/assets/img/oblako/cloud_one.png");
  position: absolute;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  animation: moon 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes moon {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.4);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="moon"></div>
```

Comment: точняк, спасибо